# Scatter plot of two signals - Shows independence?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, independence

If we have 2 signals, and we want to show that they are independent, I came across a reference where the scatter plot for both was shown, and from the scatter plot, it was written that the signals are independent. I am unable to understand what a scatter plot between 2 signals x1 and x2 would signify.

Comment: Perhaps you can share with the readers the reference where you found this remarkable assertion about scatter plots showing independence?

Comment: Yes. A scatter plot might be indicative of the two being uncorrelated, but independence is a whole other issue.

Comment: Independence has a clear definition: Two things are independent if all their joint densities are the product of the marginal densities of the components. Therefore, showing independence from observation is hard, if not even impossible; you need to make additional assumptions, namely on ergodicity, to even start making statements on the signal's stochastic properties from observation. You might not need to find the actual densities, there's some other tricks (mostly, through mutual information) that you could use to show that's the case, but "I have a scatter plot" will never suffice.

Comment: I *especially* dislike scatter plots because in many cases they're used they're used in an unreflected, dangerous manner: a scatterplot with a handful data points is useless, because the chances that you're just seeing a random pattern is high, unless you have a good statistical model that says the significance of these samples is high, but then the scatterplot is way less interesting than just stating the resulting parameters and a confidence; the visualization doesn't *give* us anything. A scatterplot with thousands of points might contain all the data necessary, but it's impossible for

Comment: a human observer to infer actual statistic properties. For example, human observers, even with a math / engineering / statistics background, when asked which one of multiple 2D scatter plots represent a pair of independent variables, usually select the sample where the points seem least "clustered", but that's not actually what 2D uniform distribution yields; so, honestly, the idea "we want to show something highly mathematical, but we're taking the detour through graphical representation" *might not be the best choice*.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, graphical representations can be great, *if you already know what to look for*. So, if there's a mathematical model of your signal that says "when you see this and that in your graphical representation, then it's caused by this thing (certainly or with high probability)". But you need to have that model *before* looking at your picture, otherwise you're just setting yourself up for seeing what you want to see.

Comment: I recommend asking this on https://stats.stackexchange.com/.